# JavaScript function for to deep copy objects

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, recursion

I've made this function for to get a deep copy (recursive copy) of objects.
=> Sub-objects **aren't** references to the sub-objects of the original object. Instead they are objects on their own.

Here's my code ...

Attention: Most of it are test data and an additional test-function.

```js
// ----- Test data ---------------------  
var swapi = [ {
  "name": "Luke Skywalker",
  "height": "1.72 m",
  "mass": "77 Kg",
  "hair_color": "Blond",
  "skin_color": "Caucasian",
  "eye_color": "Blue",
  "birth_year": "19 BBY",
  "gender": "Male",
  "homeworld": "http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
  "films": [
    "http://swapi.co/api/films/1/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/films/2/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/films/3/"
  ],
  "species": [
    "http://swapi.co/api/species/1/"
  ],
  "vehicles": [
    "http://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"
  ],
  "starships": [
    "http://swapi.co/api/starships/12/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/starships/22/"
  ],
  "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
  "edited": "2014-12-10T13:52:43.172000Z",
  "url": "http://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
},
             {
             "name": "C-3PO",
             "height": "167",
             "mass": "75",
             "hair_color": "n/a",
             "skin_color": "gold",
             "eye_color": "yellow",
             "birth_year": "112BBY",
             "gender": "n/a",
             "homeworld": "http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
             "films": [
             "http://swapi.co/api/films/5/",
             "http://swapi.co/api/films/4/",
             "http://swapi.co/api/films/6/",
             "http://swapi.co/api/films/3/",
             "http://swapi.co/api/films/2/",
             "http://swapi.co/api/films/1/"
            ],
    "species": [
      "http://swapi.co/api/species/2/"
    ],
      "vehicles": [],
        "starships": [],
          "created": "2014-12-10T15:10:51.357000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.309000Z",
              "url": "http://swapi.co/api/people/2/"
},
  {
    "name": "R2-D2",
      "height": "96",
        "mass": "32",
          "hair_color": "n/a",
            "skin_color": "white, blue",
              "eye_color": "red",
                "birth_year": "33BBY",
                  "gender": "n/a",
                    "homeworld": "http://swapi.co/api/planets/8/",
                      "films": [
                        "http://swapi.co/api/films/5/",
                        "http://swapi.co/api/films/4/",
                        "http://swapi.co/api/films/6/",
                        "http://swapi.co/api/films/3/",
                        "http://swapi.co/api/films/2/",
                        "http://swapi.co/api/films/1/",
                        "http://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
                      ],
                        "species": [
                          "http://swapi.co/api/species/2/"
                        ],
                          "vehicles": [],
                            "starships": [],
                              "created": "2014-12-10T15:11:50.376000Z",
                                "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.311000Z",
                                  "url": "http://swapi.co/api/people/3/"
  }
];

// --- Start : THE ACTUAL FUNCTION ---------------

/** Supplies a deep copy of an object.
 * 
 * @param { Object } obj - The object to copy.
 * @return { Object } - Copy of the given object.
 * @throws { Object } When given object is not 
 *   of type object.
 *
 * -- Usage example -------------------------------
 * var copyOfObj = getDeepCopy({ a: 3, b: 5 });
 */

function getDeepCopy(obj) {
  var ret;

  if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
    throw {
      message: 'Object expected as parameter.'
    }
  }

  ret = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {    
      let current = obj[key];

      if (typeof current !== 'object') {
        ret[key] = current;
      } else {  
        ret[key] = getDeepCopy(current);
      }
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
// --- End : THE ACTUAL FUNCTION ------------------

// -------- TESTING --------------------------------

function testGetDeepCopy(original, copy) {
  var originalLength = Object.keys(original).length;
  var copyLength = Object.keys(copy).length;
  var errorMessages = '';       

  if (originalLength !== copyLength) {  
    errorMessages += 'Count properties original is ' +
      originalLength + ' but count of properties copy is ' +
      copyLength + '.'
  }

  for (var prop in original) {
    if (typeof original[prop] !== 'object') {
      if (original[prop] !== copy[prop]) {
        errorMessages += ' Original value is ' + original[prop] +
          ' but copy value is ' + copy[prop] + '.';
      }
    } else {    
      if (original[prop] === copy[prop]) {
        errorMessages +=
          ' Original and copy reference is same object.';
      } else {
        let tmp = testGetDeepCopy(original[prop], copy[prop]);

        if (tmp !== 'Test passed.') {
          errorMessages + ' ' + tmp;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!errorMessages) {
    return 'Test passed.';
  } else {
    return errorMessages.trim();
  }
}

try {
  swapi.forEach(function(swObj, i) {
    console.log('Test %s (%s) : %s',
                i,
                swObj.name,
                testGetDeepCopy(swObj, getDeepCopy(swObj)));
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

I leave it in there because I would be interested in:

- Hints and comments to the actual function: Would it work as expected? Could it be improved. Or would be better to take a complete different approach?
- Documentation: Done a proper way? Can one understand at once how the function has to be used? Or must it be improved?
- Testing: Does it cover everything what is important? Possible improvements?

Looking forward to read your answers.

Comment: Chromium/WebKit js shim layer (and probably lots of other js software) simply uses `var deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source))` for the simple data shown in your code. Do some benchmarks to compare the speed of your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here some points I got from your code.

The use of `var` and `let`.

The `var` keyword defines a variable with a scope of the function where the variable is declared.

The `let` keyword defines a variable with local scope.

In your case the `ret` variable could be also declared using the `let` keyword, and it works because it is declared at the top of the function, so the local scope is the whole function.

But, in this case you're right to use `var`, just to indicate that the variable have a function scope.

However, you should use `let` in the `for` loop:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    ...
```

Here the variable `key` should not have a function scope at all.

The second point is still in your `for` loop.

You check the `key` if exists inside the object `obj`, but you don't need this check, as you are using the `in` operator that gets an object's real key.

So just remove this part.

I don't know where you use this code, so I'm not sure about the usefulness of this suggestion, but you could add a parameter to limit how deep you're copying.

The reason is to avoid issues in case of very deep object structures, and circular references.

You could check if the parameter is set and limit the copy just in that case.

About improving your test:  to be sure that `copy` is a different object to `original`, and not just a reference, you should add some negative checks, like changing the original object and test that the value in the copy object is not changed. Or add a new property, and check that it is not in the copy.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the `typeof` operator, because in javascript `null` is a Object.

```
typeof null === "object" // this returns true
```

You need to make sure that the function will not have a strange behavior when `null` is passed to it.

The array being tested only have strings and arrays as children, you should try adding other types of properties like `undefined`, `integers` or `function` (if necessary).

---

you should take a look in the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library, its a excellent 'utility-belt library', and even if you dont wanna use it in your code, you can use it as a reference. (though, they don't have a deepCopy function)

Comment: You are right. Not checking for null was definitely a weak point in there. Thanks a lot.